# Run macro when hyperlink makes another cell Active

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for ability to execute code below, after hyperlink is clicked.

Example: Hyperlink in A2 selects cell A300. When A2 is clicked and cell A300 is now an active cell, need below code to run.

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This sounds like a `beforeclick` event, where you verify the cell clicked is the appropriate cell (contains a hyperlink, etc.).

Comment: Is the hyperlink in `A2` constructed using the `HYPERLINK` function?

Comment: @BigBen - It's right click/link

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.followhyperlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```